# ZF2 Unit test of login in wierd code

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework, zend-framework2, solid-principles

I am new to ZF2 and I want to test the login method in a legacy application. Or introduce Unit tests in old code :).
The code that I have is not done according to the manual; it seems super strange if I compare it to the manual examples or even best practices.
I the login method like this:

http://pastebin.com/ZzvuBcGe

in this case the legacy is that Helper, Carts, Users, Userslogs and Usertests are models .... all of them extend DB.

In the module.config.php I have this code:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
        'AuthService' => function ($sm) {
            $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
            $dbTableAuthAdapter = new DbTableAuthAdapter(
                $dbAdapter,
                'tbl_user',
                'USER_LOGIN',
                'USER_PASSWORD',
                'MD5(?)'
            );
            $authService = new AuthenticationService();
            $authService->setAdapter($dbTableAuthAdapter);
            $authService->setStorage(new StorageSession('session'));
            return $authService;
        },
        'Helper' => function ($sm) {
            return new Helper($sm);
        },
        'Users' => function ($sm) {
            return new Users($sm);
        },
        'Carts' => function ($sm) {
            return new Carts($sm);
        }
...
```

I know that the DbTableAuthAdapter is deprecated but I have to understand how to modify this in order to change it in the best way possible. I have the feeling if I change this all the User, Carts etc models will crash.

My Unit test is like this for the moment:

```
<?php namespace ApplicationTest\Controller;
use Application\Controller\LoginController;

use Zend\Stdlib\ArrayUtils;
use Zend\Test\PHPUnit\Controller\AbstractHttpControllerTestCase;

class LoginControllerTest extends AbstractHttpControllerTestCase
{
protected $traceError = true;

public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    // The module configuration should still be applicable for tests.
    // You can override configuration here with test case specific values,
    // such as sample view templates, path stacks, module_listener_options,
    // etc.
    $configOverrides = [];

    $this->setApplicationConfig(ArrayUtils::merge(
        // Grabbing the full application configuration:
        include __DIR__ . '/../../../../../config/application.config.php',
        $configOverrides
    ));

}

public function loginCredentialsProvider()
{
    return [
        ['userDev', '12345'],
    ];
}

/**
 * @covers LoginController::loginAction()
 * @dataProvider loginCredentialsProvider
 * @param $username
 * @param $password
 */
public function testLogin($username, $password)
{
    // prepare request
//$this->getRequest()
//->setMethod('POST')
//->setPost(new Parameters(array(
//'user_login' => $username,
//'user_password' => $password
//)));
$helperMock = $this->getMockBuilder('Application\Model\Helper')
->disableOriginalConstructor()
->getMock();
$serviceManager = $this->getApplicationServiceLocator();
$serviceManager->setAllowOverride(true);
$serviceManager->setService('Application\Model\Helper', $helperMock);

    // send request
    $this->dispatch('/login', 'POST', $this->loginCredentialsProvider());

    $this->assertEquals('userDev12345', $username . $password);
//        $this->markTestIncomplete('login incomplete');
}

/**
 * @depends testLogin
 */
public function testLogout()
{
    $this->markTestIncomplete('logout incomplete');
}
}
```

I tried different ways to test but no succes and of course that I get errors:

```
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException: An exception was raised while creating "Helper"; no instance returned
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:930
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:1057
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:633
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:593
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:525
/project/module/Application/src/Application/Controller/LoginController.php:38
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractActionController.php:83
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:468
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:207
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractController.php:116
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/DispatchListener.php:113
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:468
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:207
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php:313
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Test/PHPUnit/Controller/AbstractControllerTestCase.php:282
/project/module/Application/test/ApplicationTest/Controller/LoginControllerTest.php:69
/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit:47
Caused by
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException: An exception was raised while creating "Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter"; no instance returned
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:930
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:1055
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:633
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:593
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:525
/project/module/Application/src/Application/Model/DB.php:17
/project/module/Application/config/module.config.php:1324
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:923
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:1057
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:633
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:593
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:525
/project/module/Application/src/Application/Controller/LoginController.php:38
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractActionController.php:83
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:468
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:207
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractController.php:116
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/DispatchListener.php:113
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:468
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:207
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php:313
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Test/PHPUnit/Controller/AbstractControllerTestCase.php:282
/project/module/Application/test/ApplicationTest/Controller/LoginControllerTest.php:69
/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit:47
Caused by
PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Notice: Undefined index: db
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/AdapterServiceFactory.php:26
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:923
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:1055
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:633
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:593
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:525
/project/module/Application/src/Application/Model/DB.php:17
/project/module/Application/config/module.config.php:1324
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:923
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:1057
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:633
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:593
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:525
/project/module/Application/src/Application/Controller/LoginController.php:38
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractActionController.php:83
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:468
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:207
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractController.php:116
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/DispatchListener.php:113
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:468
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:207
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php:313
/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Test/PHPUnit/Controller/AbstractControllerTestCase.php:282
/project/module/Application/test/ApplicationTest/Controller/LoginControllerTest.php:69
/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit:47
```

The issues that I have are first how to get the test to pass with this code? I know that normally you do the test and after that the code but I need a starting point to understand the mess that I have in the application. Second, what is the easy or the best way to modify the "models" to not be a dependency for each method and then pass the test? How to modify the deprecated DbTableAuthAdapter in order not to brake all things?
Like i said I am new to ZF2 and Phpunit and I am stuck over this messy code and I have the best practices in my mind but I don't know how to put them in action in this code. Thank you for all the info that I will receive for this.

LATER EDIT
the solution is to add this line in the test, foreach model:

```
    // access via application object..
    $bla = $this->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('Tests');
```

Comment: Note - on SO you're welcome to answer your own question then mark it as accepted. If you fixed your own problem this is 100% acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution is to add this line in the test, foreach model:

$bla = $this->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('Tests');

Thank you i336_ :)